# Proof using double counting

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Give two proofs that $$ (2n)! = \binom{2n}{n} \cdot (n!)^2 $$

I've already determined how to prove it algebraically (I think):

$\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$

$(2n)! = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} *(n!)^2$

$(2n)! = (2n)!$

But how would you go about proving it through double counting? Any pointers on how to formulate the proof would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Note that for the proof you have given, the algebra is correct but the logic is backwards.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  You can order a set of $2n$ elements by the following procedure:

- choose, without regard to order, the first $n$ elements in the list;
- order these elements;
- order the last $n$ elements of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The bumer $(2n)!$ counts permutations of $2n$ objects. You can permute these arbitrarily, or you can first choose a subset of $n$ elements, permute these and permute the complement. Both actions are equivalent, and one can be done in $(2n)!$ ways, while the other can be done in $\binom{2n}nn!n!$ ways: first choose the $n$-subset in $\binom{2n}n$ ways, permute one set in $n!$ ways and the complement in $n!$ ways. Note that this proves more generally that  $$(n+m)!=\binom{m+n}n n!m!$$